# Zoom-out for manim Axes

Tags: python-3.x, manim

Suppose we have an `Axes` object and a graph plotted in the coordinate system defined by these axes.

Is it possible to "zoom-out" by one or both axes, so we can see more of the graph, while the dimensions of the Coordinate system on the screen are kept constant?

For example, I've tried using the `ValueTracker` for both `x_range` properties of the `Axes` and the `graph` but it gives strange and unexpected results.

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        x_max_tracker = ValueTracker(0.0)
        axes = always_redraw(lambda: Axes(
            (-np.pi, x_max_tracker.get_value(), 0.5), (-5., 5.),
            width=8, height=10
        ))
        
        xsin_graph = always_redraw(
            lambda: axes.get_graph(
                lambda x: 0.5*x*np.sin(x)-1, color=BLUE,
                x_range=[-np.pi, x_max_tracker.get_value()]
            )
        )
        self.play(
            Write(axes, lag_ratio=0.01, run_time=1), ShowCreation(xsin_graph)
        )
        
        self.wait(2)
        
        self.play(x_max_tracker.animate.set_value(4*np.pi), run_time=2)
```

Additional, but connected question: is it possible to give the position of the coordinate system (`Axes`) at initiation?

##### UPDATE

I have defined a method `generate_axes()` which: 1) generates the `Axes` object; 2) Places it at specified coordinates on the `Scene`.

Now, if I am calling the `always_redraw` method on this `generate_axes()` method (keeping the `x_tracker` from the code above to control the `x_range`) then I could obtain nice "zoom-out/in" animation by calling `play(x_tracker.animate.set_value(X))`.

However, this doesn't change the `axes` variable, which is, apparently, still keeping the pointer on the first initial `Axes` object with not modified `x_range`. I thought that `always_redraw()` creates a new `mobject` each frame? Somehow this updated object is transferred to the `Scene` to be displayed but can't be accessed! For example, if I print `axes.x_range` after the end of the animation I am getting the initial `x_range` value.

P.S.: I am using the `manimgl` package, so the method `always_redraw` is probably not from the standard `manim` package. But it is generally the `add_updater` with `become`

Answer (score 2):

Currently, `Axes` unfortunately do not support the sort of rescaling you would like to use. The easiest way to achieve this sort of behavior probably is by implementing a custom animation that repeatedly updates the axes and any curves within with `become`.

And as for your second question: `Axes` are always drawn in a way such that the center of the mobject is in the scene origin. You can move them to where you would like to show them, and only `add` them after moving.

#### Update

`.become` creates a new mobject, yes, but then only transfers some of the new mobject's properties and attributes to the original mobject. If there are some attributes that you need updated, it is best if you simply updated them yourself in your method -- which is also why using a general updater function is more flexible than `always_redraw`.

And for future reference: make sure to say right away whether you are working with `manim` or `manimgl`, they are substantially different in some aspects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated my question with the follow up =)

Comment: thanks again for the attention. I've looked precisely into how the `.become()` is defined: it copies only the `data` attribute of the `mobject` which is sufficient for shapes, but not sufficient for complex `VGroup`-like structures (i.e. `Axes`). I've made a method that does copy everything, but it is too slow to run each frame.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to do what you expected, but maybe you already found it before.

The way I managed to do the animation is to create another instance of the axis. Instead of having "axes.get_graph" you buils the same axes followed by .get_graph. Then, it always recreates  the graph.

Actually I was also looking for the answer and what gave me a hint is "However, this doesn't change the axes variable"

Maybe it is not a beautiful way to sort it out, but it works